# Saving .eml file with X-Unsent: 1 is not working for Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: c#, outlook, lotus-notes, eml

The .eml file created with below contents works appropriately in Outlook, however, when you open it with Lotus Notes 8.5 - it's not shown as draft email. It comes-up as a normal email, like it is in Inbox. If I try to Forward the email, then the image section is shown with a RED X.

I need to create an draft email which can be opened both in Outlook and Lotus Notes with HTML body. Any suggestions on how to create an .eml file for Lotus Notes?

I am using C#, to generate the .eml file.

```
        X-Sender: test@localhost.com
        X-Receiver: Test@gmail.com
        X-Unsent: 1
        MIME-Version: 1.0
        From: test@localhost.com
        To: Test@gmail.com
        Date: 23 Jan 2017 11:42:31 +1100
        Subject: Test subject
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

        <br /><strong>Test body</strong><img src=3D'http://www.w3schools.=
        com/tags/smiley.gif' width=3D'42' height=3D'42'>
```

Appreciate any guidance on this part.

Comment: Lotus Notes shows an email as a draft if it has no PostedDate or DeliveredDate. These are internal items within the Notes mail document structure; they don't correspond to standard headers.You could try omitting the Date: header in your .eml file, but Notes might supply the current date if you do that so I'm not sure if it will work. (That's why this is a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: Another thing to try would be using x-notes-item headers with no value. E.g., x-notes-item: ; name="DeliveredDate" and one for "PostedDate", too. I suspect this won't work, though, because I think it's the existence of the items, not the value, that matters, and this will probably create the items but give them empty values. Still might be worth a shot, though, if omitting the Date: header doesn't work.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz thanks for your response. I tried with date, and it didn't solve the problem. When I double click on eml file, it opens up in lotus notes, however, it says "Notes error: you are not authorized to perform that operation".

Comment: @RichardSchwartz please let me know, what I should do with that "name" and "posteddate". I didn't got the syntax here.

Comment: The 'You are not auhtorized' message normally indicates that you have an ACL error. It's not clear to me why you would be getting that when opening a .eml file. I used the exact header syntax for x-note-item up above. I will describe it again here: x-notes-item colon space semicolon name equals-sign double-quote PostedDate double-quote.